# Loop XML with namespace in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, namespaces, powershell-cmdlet

I try to loop an XML that contains namespace but it does not work (I use loop because I need to do things inside the loop).

Example without namespace that works perfectly

```
$XmlDocument = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xx>
    <Envelope>
        <Client>Cusomer</Client>
    </Envelope>
    <Data>
        <Item>
            <Number>11111</Number>
            <Balance>2</Balance>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Number>2222</Number>
            <Balance>4</Balance>
        </Item>
    </Data>
</xx>
'@;

foreach ($record in $XmlDocument.xx.Data.Item)
{
    #Do stuff
    Write-Host $record.Number
    Write-Host $record.Balance    
    #Do stuff
}
```

I try to do the same thing and want the same result with an XML that has namespace. Have read that you should use `-Namespace` but I must using it wrong. I get the error that I need something on the right side of `-Namespace`.

```
$XmlDocument = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xx.yy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration IntegrationDocumentSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration">
    <Envelope>
        <Client>Cusomer</Client>
    </Envelope>
    <Data>
        <Item>
            <Number>11111</Number>
            <Balance>2</Balance>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Number>2222</Number>
            <Balance>4</Balance>
        </Item>
    </Data>
</xx.yy>
'@;

$XmlNamespace = @{ ns = 'http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration'; };

foreach ($record in $XmlDocument.xx.yy.Data.Item -Namespace $XmlNamespace)
{
    #Do stuff
    Write-Host $record.Number
    Write-Host $record.Balance    
    #Do stuff
}
```

Comment: The problem here is the node `xx.yy`. You need to include the `.` as part of the property name when using the access operator `.` -> `$XmlDocument.'xx.yy'.Data.Item`. Otherwise, the interpreter thinks you are accessing property `yy` as a subproperty of `xx`.

Comment: If you must use the namespace, then one way is to use `Select-Xml` with your namespace prefixing your XPath elements -> `foreach ($record in (Select-Xml -Xml $XmlDocument -XPath '/ns:xx.yy/ns:Data/ns:Item' -Namespace $XmlNamespace).Node)`

Comment: @AdminOfThings I don't need to use the namespace but the XML have the namespace and I cannot get the XML without the namespace.

Comment: @Xtreme But this is not an issue with namespaces. All you need is `$XmlDocument.'xx.yy'.Data.Item` - did you give it a try?

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks @AdminOfThings

Comment: @AdminOfThings, I encourage you to turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in this scenario is incorrectly accessing the node `xx.yy` as a deserialized property. The `.` is the member access operator when used in the syntax `$object.property1.property2.property3`. To include a `.` in a property name, you must instruct the parser accordingly. We can use quotes around a property name to include special characters.

```
$XmlDocument = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xx.yy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration IntegrationDocumentSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration">
    <Envelope>
        <Client>Cusomer</Client>
    </Envelope>
    <Data>
        <Item>
            <Number>11111</Number>
            <Balance>2</Balance>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Number>2222</Number>
            <Balance>4</Balance>
        </Item>
    </Data>
</xx.yy>
'@

foreach ($record in $XmlDocument.'xx.yy'.Data.Item) {
    Write-Host $record.Number
    Write-Host $record.Balance
}
```

---

If you must use the namespace, then one way is to use `Select-Xml` with your namespace prefixing your XPath elements.

```
$XmlDocument = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xx.yy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration IntegrationDocumentSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration">
    <Envelope>
        <Client>Cusomer</Client>
    </Envelope>
    <Data>
        <Item>
            <Number>11111</Number>
            <Balance>2</Balance>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Number>2222</Number>
            <Balance>4</Balance>
        </Item>
    </Data>
</xx.yy>
'@

$XmlNamespace = @{ ns = 'http://xx.se/schemas/xx.yy/3.0/integration' }
$SelectedNodes = (Select-Xml -Xml $XmlDocument -XPath '/ns:xx.yy/ns:Data/ns:Item' -Namespace $XmlNamespace).Node
foreach ($record in $SelectedNodes) {
    Write-Host $record.Number
    Write-Host $record.Balance
}
```